# Apple Calendar travel times for hybrid work

Tags: calendar

I use my Mac Calendar strictly for personal use, but my job is such that I can make personal appointments during the workday. I have a hybrid work schedule, where I work from home the same two days a week every week. I want to travel time to be calculated from my Work address on Mon Tue & Thu, and from my Home address on Wed and Fri. Is there a way to set that up or at least just let me choose which location to use -- home or work -- when I create the appointment?

This guide: https://support.apple.com/guide/calendar/add-location-and-travel-time-to-events-icl43600/mac says to set work hours using the "Day starts/ends at" fields in General Preferences, but that apparently assumes I work from the same location every day during those times. I also saw that I can override the default of using work address during the "days starts/ends at" times by putting 12pm in both fields. However, that changes to always use the home address. I realize I can just manually enter a travel time, but I'm in So Cal and travel time for the same distance can be 10 minutes or an hour depending on the time of day so having the calendar provide the time based on traffic and weather really helps.

Comment: I don’t know about Apple Calendar, but Outlook calculates travel time based on where I am currently, not where the appointment was made or from a predetermined location (home/work).  I would imagine Calendar does the same thing since it needs access to location services